# Draw a closed liquid-droped shaped curve with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I am trying to draw a closed liquid-droped shaped curve using TikZ, but I don't know how. I tried to draw it using coordinates but I don't think that this is the solution. I am using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[very thick] (0,4) to [out=90,in=195] (0.1,3.9);
%\draw [shorten >=-1cm,shorten <=-1cm] (0,3) to [bend right=5](0.1,2.9);
\draw[orange, very thick] (0,4) -- (-0.1,3.5) -- (-0.3,3) -- (-0.65,2.7) -- (-0.55,2) -    - (-0.2,1.2) -- (0,0) -- (0.2,0.4) -- (1,1) -- (0.8,2.3) -- (0.5,2.8) -- (0.25,3.5) -- (0.1,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Avalanche Multiplication}%
\label{fig:avalanche}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: liquid-droped shape]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[very thick, orange] (-0.1,5) .. controls (-4,-2) and (4,-2) .. (0.1,5);
\node at (0,3) {$+$};
\node at (0,2) {$+$};
\node at (0.5,2.5) {$-$};
\node at (-0.5,2.5) {$+$};
\node at (0.5,.5) {$-$};
\node at (-0.5,1.5) {$-$};
\node at (0.5,1) {$-$};
\node at (0.5,2.5) {$-$};
\node at (-0.5,.5) {$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Avalanche Multiplication}%
\label{fig:avalanche}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the plus sign really need in math mode?

Comment: @GarbageCollector: Ah! only personal preference. It looks good IMO (I am not partial, you know. Whatever is true for `-`, will be true for `+` ;).

Comment: Thank you very much!!!That was exactly what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 24):

Are you perhaps interested in something like:

[image]

Similar results could be achieved by means of the [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\draw[orange, very thick] (0,4) .. (-0.1,3.5) .. (-0.3,3) .. (-0.65,2.7) .. (-0.55,2) .. (-0.2,1.2) .. (0,0) .. (0.2,0.4) .. (1,1) .. (0.8,2.3) .. (0.5,2.8) .. (0.25,3.5) .. cycle;

\foreach \place/\el in {{(0,1.2)/+},{(0,3)/-},{(0.5,2.5)/+},{(0.7,1)/-},{(-0.2,2.5)/-},{(0.1,2)/+},{(0.6,1.5)/+}}
\node at \place {\ensuremath{\el}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Avalanche Multiplication}%
\label{fig:avalanche}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

From the comments seems clear I misunderstood the question; a belated attempt to remedy (*of course with hobby*) :):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}

Completely closed:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[orange, very thick] (0,4) to[curve through={(-0.45,2)..(-0.9,0) .. (0.9,0) .. (0.45,2)}] (0,4);

\foreach \place/\el in {{(0,1.2)/-},{(0,2.8)/-},{(-0.5,0.8)/+},{(0.55,1)/-},{(-0.2,1.7)/-},{(0.1,2)/+},{(0.55,1.5)/+},{(0.2,0.5)/+},{(-0.2,0.2)/-}}
\node at \place {\ensuremath{\el}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

Not closed:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[orange, very thick] (-0.035,4) to[curve through={(-0.45,2)..(-0.9,0) .. (0.9,0) .. (0.45,2)}] (0.035,4);

\foreach \place/\el in {{(0,1.2)/-},{(0,2.8)/-},{(-0.5,0.8)/+},{(0.55,1)/-},{(-0.2,1.7)/-},{(0.1,2)/+},{(0.55,1.5)/+},{(0.2,0.5)/+},{(-0.2,0.2)/-}}
\node at \place {\ensuremath{\el}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Since Garbage Collector posted a very nice PSTricks gif animation, it sounds to me that we should have also a TikZ-based version. Basically, the `standalone` class with the `tikz` option allows to create several pdf pages, the base of the animation. The `+` and `-` signs change position in each page because their coordinates are generated by random numbers, the function `rnd` which generates number from 0 to 1. That's why each time a random number is created, it is multiplied by a constant factor that amplifies and bounds the positions in which each sign will be placed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\foreach \number in {1,...,20}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[orange, very thick] (0,4) to[curve through={(-0.45,2)..(-0.9,0) .. (0.9,0) .. (0.45,2)}] (0,4);
\foreach \place/\el in {{(rnd*0.8,rnd*1.05)/-},{(rnd*0.05,rnd*2.8)/-},{(-rnd*0.5,0.8)/+},{(rnd*0.55,rnd*1.1)/-},{(-rnd*0.2,rnd*1.7)/-},{(rnd*0.4,1.8)/+},{(rnd*0.55,1.5)/+},{(rnd*0.9,rnd*0.9)/+},{(-rnd*0.9,rnd*0.4)/-}}
\node at \place {\ensuremath{\el}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but thank you very much for `hobby`!!!

Comment: @Thanos: oh.. I've seen the point just after your comments! I've edited my answer to accomplish the right task `;)`

Comment: The minus sign should be in math mode, I think.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: I think that's a personal taste and Haris's answer already shows the result in math mode. But if you convince me that it is fundamental, I can edit my answer `;)`

Comment: Thank you very much!!!That is exactly what I wanted! Sorry for the incovinience on my question!

Comment: @Thanos: that was my fault, not yours; I've just taken your minimal working example and I've not read carefully the question `:)`

Comment: Thank you anyway! However there is an issue... When I compile your code I get an error `I can't find file tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: The `-` is a sign (negative). Without dollar it is just a `dash` (hyphen) used in text. I feel `$-$` is better.

Comment: @HarishKumar: ok, you convinced me! `:)` I'll edit my answer in a minute! @Thanos: probably your distribution isn't updated. The `hobby` package is quite recent!

Comment: @Thanos CTAN tells me that hobby is now in TeXLive and MikTeX so if you update your distribution you'll get it.  Or you can manually install it.  But Claudio is right, it is quite new so if you haven't updated recently you won't have it.

Comment: OK! You are really in stuff!!! I appreciate it!

Comment: A reference to find the `hobby` package: [Where in the world is tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86363/where-in-the-world-is-tikzlibraryhobby-code-tex)

Comment: Note that the `.. cycle` syntax no longer works with `hobby`.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121310/86 for details and how to fix it.

Answer (score 15):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

### Still Version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\N{15}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,5)
    \psclip{\psbezier[linestyle=none](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)}
        \psLoop{\N}{
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$+$}
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$-$}}%
    \endpsclip
    \psbezier[linecolor=orange](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### GIF Version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\N{15}
\begin{document}
\psLoop{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,5)
    \psclip{\psbezier[linestyle=none](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)}
        \psLoop{\N}{
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$+$}
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$-$}}%
    \endpsclip
    \psbezier[linecolor=orange](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are joking!!!This is awsome!!!

Comment: Holy `animated` ghost ;). Searching for proper word!