# Undefined control sequence error in pspicture

Tags: errors, pstricks

I found this interesting question 
[Draw a closed liquid-droped shaped curve with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73614/draw-closed-curve-in-tikz)
for which an even interesting answer was provided by the user Garbage Collector.

Just for the fun of it, I tried compiling his answer on my system, which I have pasted here:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\N{15}
\begin{document}
\psLoop{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,5)
    \psclip{\psbezier[linestyle=none](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)}
        \psLoop{\N}{
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$+$}
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$-$}}%
    \endpsclip
    \psbezier[linecolor=orange](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

I received 120 error messages, all of them read: `13: Undefined control sequence \end{pspicture}}`. Can someone shed any light on this matter?

Comment: The code works OK here. Did you compile with latex instead of pdflatex?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yeah that was the error. I used `pdflatex` instead of `latex`. I haven't used anything other than `pdflatex`. What's the output I should expect while using `latex`? I tried opening the .dvi file that was generated but it shows an unexpected result. While scrolling down on the .dvi file I got the error:

Comment: Error: /undefined in tx@Dict
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1914   1   3   %oparray_pop   1913   1   3   %oparray_pop   1897   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --

Comment: nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--   --dict:95/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript  9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: @convert the dvi to pdf using dvipdf, for example.

Comment: [pstricks info (from the tag)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/pstricks/info) can we close this as too localized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code that compiles the PSTricks code behind the scene. You just need to type `pdflatex -shell-escape main` in your terminal or DOS command window.

In the directory in which this input file exists, you will get GIF animation, PDF animation, PNG frames. Make sure that you have installed ImageMagick (the latest version is recommended to make sure that `remove` option is available).

```
% this filename is main.tex
% compile it with "pdflatex -shell-escape main" (without the quotes)

\documentclass[preview,border={7pt 0pt 7pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{WaterDrop.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\N{15}
\begin{document}
\psLoop{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,5)
    \psclip{\psbezier[linestyle=none](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)}
        \psLoop{\N}{
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$+$}
            \rput(!rand 21 mod 10 div 1 sub rand 51 mod 10 div 1 sub){$-$}}%
    \endpsclip
    \psbezier[linecolor=orange](0,5)(-6.8,-4.3)(6.8,-4.3)(0,5)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{latex WaterDrop}
\immediate\write18{dvips WaterDrop}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf WaterDrop.ps}% sometimes you need to disable auto rotate in ps2pdf. Please follow up if you really need it!
% delete auxiliary files generated by the 3 commands above.
% cmd /c del WaterDrop.ext is Windows command, adapt it to other OS.
\makeatletter
\@for\x:={tex,dvi,ps,log,aux}\do{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del WaterDrop.\x}}
\makeatother

% convert to GIF animation
\immediate\write18{convert -delay 100 -loop 0 -density 200 -alpha remove WaterDrop.pdf WaterDrop.gif}

% convert to PNG
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 200 -alpha on WaterDrop.pdf WaterDrop-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
%\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=<integer>]{<frame rate>}{<PDF filename without extension>}{<left blank>}{<left blank>}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{3}{WaterDrop}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For more details, see [How to create animations and videos in a single input file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74076/9467).