# Putting animations into latex beamer presentation. Use png, gif?

Tags: beamer, animations, gif

I need to put an animation into a slideshow I am making using the beamer package for LaTex. Ideally I would like it to loop and play again and again like a GIF, but anything similar would work as well. I used MatLab to generate the figures (right now I just have a sequence of pictures, but I should be able to put it into any format necessary). I know there is an animator function in beamer, but I've no idea how to really use it. I've also seen some places that using PNG files can accomplish the same result as GIF's, but once again I'm not sure how to do this.

I found a similar question on this site, but they seem to have LaTex generating the figures??? Besides when I copied the code into my editor it didn't run. I really like the format of the animation in this example, but no idea how to adapt it to work for me. Here is the link to the page:
[Similar Question with Answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74073/gif-image-in-beamer-presentation)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `animate` package. Its `\animategraphics` command will take your external images and put them in an animation. So, assuming that you have images `image1.jpg`, ... `image6.jpg`  (or in any other format recognized by LaTeX), write:

```
\animategraphics[controls]{1}{image}{1}{6}
```

(Btw, this works also in a "normal" document, i.e. in a non-`beamer` class.)

Comment: Thanks so much it works great. Quick question, is there a way to get the controls like the one in the example and/or tell it how many frames (pictures) to do per second. I know I'm being picky now, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Sure: the controls are already present in whta I wrote (optional arg `controls`). The first mandatory arg controls the framerate (above, 1 (Hz)). And, it's all the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf)! ;-)

Comment: Oh, I took the word controls out to change the size. Oops XD I didn't know that there was a manual. Thanks you so much!!! This is going to MAKE my presentation.

Comment: @Logan: You asked for playing in a loop: Just add `,loop` to the option list.

Comment: This currently isn't working for me. Is this feature widely implemented by PDF readers, or could that be my problem?

Comment: @MHaaZ: You need Adobe Reader for this.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović, what about only one gif image? How to include it and animate it?

Comment: @Sigur I'm not sure I understand what you mean by animating a single image.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović, I mean: how to include a `gif` file so that when I show the frame containing it the `gif` starts to animate (as it does when we open it with the browser, for example). But I guess that `gif` is not supported.

Comment: @Sigur You can use Imagemagick to convert the GIF to a series of PNG frames, and use this method to play back the series of image files.

Comment: Does LaTeX support APNG (Animated PNG)?