# Unable to put an animation into a LaTeX Beamer document

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

**Goal:**

- I have PDF images titled `pert_u_3_num_0`, ..., `pert_u_3_num_149`
- I would like to create an animation out of these images, and insert it into a LaTeX Beamer document (with video controls)
- the PDF images and the LaTeX Beamer document are located in the same folder

I have written a LaTeX Beamer document `test.tex` (whose full content is given below) by following the instructions on [Putting animations into latex beamer presentation. Use png, gif?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99359/putting-animations-into-latex-beamer-presentation-use-png-gif), which successfully generates `test.pdf`.

**Problem and question:**

- Unfortunately, the resulting `test.pdf` displays `pert_u_3_num_0` as a "poster slide" (with video controls underneath it), but clicking on this "poster slide" does not start an animation (and the video controls don't work and cannot even be clicked on). Could you let me know how to resolve this issue and get a running animation embedded in my LaTeX Beamer document?

**TeX file `test.tex`:**

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\title[long-title]{short-title}
\author{author-name}
\institute[short-inst-name]{long-institution-name}
\date[location-2015]{date-when-talk-is-given}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Slide for video}
\begin{center}
    \animategraphics[autoplay, controls]{15}{pert_u_3_num_}{0}{149}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What pdf viewer are you using? The `animate` package says in its doc that are required "Adobe Reader, version ≥ 7 or PDF-XChange Viewer (with option ‘method=widget’ or ‘method=ocg’)".

Comment: Okular supports it too since 2019 in Linux