Putting GIF in beamer
I'm trying to add a GIF and I have the following error:

I tried different ways but nothing works:

\animategraphics - I get a long list of weird errors, and yes I have the images in png format
\multiinclude - it put every image on a different page instead of doing a GIF out of the images.
i tried converting to a video, still no luck

The code:
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \movie[loop]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{imagine-0}}{gif3.gif}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

I also tried:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \animategraphics[loop,width=12cm]{10}{gif3-}{0}{12}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

it doesn't work.

Welcome! Could you make a complete minimal example and paste the code here as text so people can reproduce it? Images of code are not great for copy-paste and they are really not great if you rely on a screen reader.

Welcome. // Without your graphics we can't test your code. Have a look here and at other Related links (right side) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99361/245790

Depending on the chosen method you will need a compatible PDF viewer for playback, e. g. Okular or Acrobat Reader.

Also, methods for video embedding most likely won't work for GIFs.

@MS-SPO i can't add the images because of the large size, I tried

You could make it smaller ... Or take another one ... we just can't test your code ...

"Doesn't work" isn't a very useful problem description. Please show which error you get with your animategraphics example.

"\multiinclude - it put every image on a different page instead of doing a GIF out of the images." That's the expected behaviour. To animate the gif, switch between the pages. Switching between pages can be automated with \transduration<0-16>{0} (replace 16 with the number of images the gif contains)

Do the files gif3-0.png through gif3-12.png exist and are they located in a directory where LaTeX can find them?

A quite robust solution is to convert the gif into a sequence of images. As you wrote correctly, each image is then placed separately on a page -- but observe that the frame number does not change. Switching from page to page can also been done automatically, e.g., using the command animategraphics from the package animate.

as I said above I also tried this but it does not work, I get I have a huge list of errors.

@user985505 Most likely a viewer problem.

I have a compatible PDF viewer the problem is that the code does not compile because of the errors
