# How can I draw top right corner trimmed rectangle in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, code

If possible I want to draw a `code` figure (looks like rectangle but right-top corner is trimmed) in tikz. Basic sample would be:

```
____
|   \
|< >|   
|___|
```

Is there any sample for this?

Original figure is taken from : https://git-lfs.com

[image]

Comment: [Related.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103688)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so?

[image: icon]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt]
    \draw (2.3,6.5) -- (-4.3,6.5) -- (-4.3,-6.6) -- (4.3,-6.6) -- (4.3,3.7) -- cycle;
    \draw (-.9,1.6) -- (-2.9,0) -- (-.9,-1.6);
    \draw (.9,1.6) -- (2.9,0) -- (.9,-1.6);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Try also these:

```
    \draw (1.5,3.25) -- (-2.65,3.25) -- (-2.65,-3.3) -- (2.85,-3.35) -- (2.85,1.85) -- cycle;
    \draw (-.45,.8) -- (-1.45,-.25) -- (-.55,-1.3);
    \draw ( .45,.8) -- ( 1.45,-.25) -- ( .55,-1.3);
```

Comment: Thanks! Having a filled folded paper inside another folded paper would be challenging right? like most right figure on my question

Comment: Not really. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686934/245790 .

Answer (score 4):

There is also the `chamfered rectangle` node shape:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tikzset{fileshape/.style 2 args={chamfered rectangle, 
    draw, ultra thick,
    chamfered rectangle corners=north east, 
    minimum height=12mm, minimum width=10mm,
    #1, label={[text=#1]270:{\sffamily #2}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fileshape={gray}{code}]at (0,0) (A){$<>$};
\node[fileshape={cyan}{file.psd}]at (2,0) (B){};
\draw[thick, gray] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to draw both icons.

The initial idea was to follow the curves for the schematized person. However, it turned out, that's not necessary and you can also put a circle at the right position, as long as the path is closed.

As was pointed out in the link inside one comment, it might be useful to use polar coordinates with the cut corners.

Also scale is rather large. Best way would be to adjust the coordinates using a calculator (or tikzlib `calc`) rather than using `scale` (see manual for details).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
% ~~~ pictures ~~~~~~~~~
\tikzset{
    symb/.pic={
    \draw (1.5,3.25) -- (-2.65,3.25) -- (-2.65,-3.3) -- (2.85,-3.35) -- (2.85,1.85) -- cycle;
    \draw (-.45,.8) -- (-1.45,-.25) -- (-.55,-1.3);
    \draw ( .45,.8) -- ( 1.45,-.25) -- ( .55,-1.3);
    }
}
\tikzset{
    pers/.pic={
    \draw (1.5,3.25) -- (-2.65,3.25) -- (-2.65,-3.3) -- (2.85,-3.35) -- (2.85,1.85) -- cycle;
    \draw [fill=black] (1.05,1.95) -- (-1.95,2)  -- (-1.95,-2) -- 
    (-0.95, -2) arc [start angle=180,end angle=90,radius=1cm] --
    ++(0,0) arc [start angle=270,end angle=-90,radius=1cm] --
    ++ (0,0)  arc [start angle=90,end angle=0,radius=1cm]
    -- (2.05,-2) -- (2.05,1) -- cycle;
    }
}
 % ~~~ demo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt]
    \pic at (0,0) {symb};
    \pic at (6,0) {pers};
    
    \pic at (12,-9) {pers};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**P.S.:** This happens, when you add a white outline to the circles of `pers`:

```
---
\draw [fill=black,draw=white] (1.05,1.95) -- (-1.95,2)   ...
```

[image: result2]

Comment: Woaw ! Thanks a lot

Comment: There are inconsistencies with some horizontal lines (3.3 vs 3.25 for example).

Comment: Right. But it's fine, as the TO probably needs to adjust anyway.