# Exporting animation created with animate package

Tags: animate

- Consider the following minimal working example.
- It's great to have an animation in pdf format.
- But sometimes it would be good to be able to **export** it into an **animated gif or something else** (swf, video file, svg?).
- How do I achieve this?
- Note: I often have animations together with pgfplots.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{animateinline}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fboxsep1mm
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
    a
    \newframe    
    b
    \newframe  
    c                 
    \end{animateinline}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Remark**

The animation is not visible in all PDF viewers. It surely works with a current **Adobe Reader**.

Comment: See my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74076/19356) that can produce many output format in one click.

Comment: New possibilities. See below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## 1 Animated SVG (`animate` `[2018/11/20]`)

- suitable for inclusion in Web pages (or viewed standalone, also on mobile devices)
- freely scalable (vectorial graphics)
- relies on M. Gieseking's `dvisvgm` output driver/utility (available in TeXLive and MikTeX)

[image]

- compile with

  ```
  latex myAnim.tex % or lualatex --output-format=dvi or xelatex --no-pdf
  dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 myAnim.dvi % or myAnim.xdv
  ```

`myAnim.tex`:

```
    \documentclass[dvisvgm,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{animate}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}\Huge
    \begin{center}

      \begin{animateinline}[controls,buttonsize=0.5em,autoplay,loop]{2}
        \multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{
          \framebox[1em]{\i}
        }
        \newframe
          \framebox[1em]{A}
        \newframe
          \framebox[1em]{B}
        \newframe
          \framebox[1em]{C}
        \newframe
          \framebox[1em]{D}
        \newframe
          \framebox[1em]{E}
        \newframe
          \framebox[1em]{F}
      \end{animateinline}

    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

- embed into HTML with the `<object>` tag

  ```
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="myAnim.svg">
    <!-- fallback & search engine indexing -->
    <img src="myAnim.svg" />
  </object>
  ```
- The Chromium Web browser and those derived from it (Chrome, Opera, ...) have by far the best rendering performance, as can be tested with the [Lorenz attractor example](https://agrahn.gitlab.io).

## 2 Export to multipage PDF (`animate` `[2018/08/22]`)

As of version `[2018/08/22]`, `animate` has the package option **`export`**, to be used together with the **`standalone`** document class, as in:

```
\documentclass[export]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
```

or

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[export]{animate}
```

Animation frames are output as individual pages of a multipage document, suitable for conversion to other file formats, such as animated GIF, using external programs, such as `convert` from ImageMagick.org:

```
convert -density 300 -delay 4 -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif
```

creates an animated GIF at 100/4=25 frames per second.

Comment: Thanks! Is was hoping for a way that doesn't include changing the internal code of the animate package.

Comment: Apparently there is no 'easy' alternative to your approach. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I might add some code to `animate` in the future that detects whether `preview` was loaded and which then takes the necessary actions.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to it. Animate is a great package - I use it a lot.

Comment: It's a very old question - I know :). Is the code now part of the official `animate` package?

Comment: Not yet. But I fixed the code here to make it functional again.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, thank you for your kind comments!!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner : I updated my answer.

Comment: Great! I only can upvote once sadly. I will upvote some other of your answers.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, you can upvote several comments.  :)

Comment: @alfC If this would make Alex happy, yes :).

Comment: How to get SVG animation from a PDF with several pages?

Comment: `dvisvgm` (version 2.3.5) contained in TeXLive does not support embedding external PDF, but the upstream version 2.6.1 does. It will very likely be in TeXLive-2019. For now, split-convert the multipage PDF to a numbered set of PS files and use `\animategraphics...`.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy Split-convert multipage PDF `input.pdf` to `output-<#page>.ps` with Ghostscript: `pdf2ps -sOutputFile=output-%d.ps input.pdf`

Comment: This is still a great answer :)

Comment: Oh, thanks, Manuel!

Answer (score 2):

Animated GIFs can be made using wolfram script  and  latexalpha2wlua.sty (windows, pdflatex, lualatex)

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579254/161015 for a complete answer.

[image: s]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage[cache]{latexalpha2wlua} % option cache (faster on the second run) or nocache (recalculate always)

\begin{document}

Produce an animated GIF in current directory 

\newcommand{\iplotx}{% 
    Animate[Plot3D[Sin[x*y +a], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 4}]
}

\wolframonlygif{\iplotx}{animaxvi}  %#2 name of animated gif 
    
\end{document}
```

In addition

(1) As part of the output an animated gif will remain in the current directory

(2) Put `latexalpha2wlua.sty` in the same directory of the document or in your local  `texmf` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: Where is the definition of the command `\wolframonlygif`? I can't find it in the package file. I think you mean `\wolframanimation`.

Comment: While digging into the script language I forgot to do the update. Sorry!! It is done now.

Comment: +1 Somehow I forgot to upvote, sorry.