# Flattening a square impulse

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, animate

I'm interested in creating a plot using TikZ or pgfplots together with the animate package.

The plot should consist of a square impulse that is moving along the `z` axis. As it moves it should lose its "squarness" and become a smoother impulse (see the image).

I *suspect* this could be done in two ways:

1. Define an impulse function of time(`\it`) which would change accordingly.
2. Draw a TikZ path with appropriate decorations that
   change with a parameter (`\it`).

How could this be done?

[image: Wave dispersion]

My first try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage[poster=first, controls, buttonsize=0.8em]{animate}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{animateinline}{10}
    \multiframe{11}{it=0+1}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis} [
                xmax = 15,
                ymax = 4,
            ]
                \addplot[domain = 0:20] coordinates {(0,0) (\it+1,0) (\it+1,1) (\it+2,1) (\it+2,0) (\it+5,0)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    }
 \end{animateinline}%
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proposal: Take a root of a sine curve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[poster=first, controls, buttonsize=0.8em]{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \tikzset{declare function={f(\x,\y)=pow(sin(180*(\x-\y)),1/(12-\y));}}
 \newcommand{\PulseOne}[1]{(0,0) --(#1,0) --
 plot[domain=#1:{#1+1},variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x,#1)}) -- ({#1+1},0) --(12,0)}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{animateinline}{10}
 \multiframe{11}{it=0+1}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-latex](0,0)--(12.5,0) node[below]{$z$};
  \draw[blue,ultra thick] \PulseOne{\it};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
 \end{animateinline}%
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I was not sure how rapidly the squareness is supposed to disappear, but you can play with exponent in f, i.e. adjust the second argument of `f`. Here is an example with

```
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x,\y)=pow(sin(180*(\x-\y)),1/(23-2*\y));}}
```

[image]

And just for fun

```
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x,\y)=0.5*pow(sin(180*(\x-\y)),1/(1+(\y-11)^2));}}
```

[image]

BTW, in order to create the animated gif images, I use the [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799) by the future Oscar winner @AlexG.

Comment: :-) you create the magnific code. +1.