# Animating vector on top of Bloch Sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a vector `a` which can only move in `x-y` plane and has magnitude of the radius of the sphere. Is there a way to make this `a` animated. Animated in the sense that it rotates within the `x-y` plane and the angle changes accordingly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Define radius
    \def\r{3}

    % Bloch vector
    \draw (0,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1] (orig) {} -- (\r/5,-\r/3) node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.7,label=above:$\vec{a}$] (a) {};

    % Sphere
    \draw (orig) circle (\r);
    \draw[dashed] (orig) ellipse (\r{} and \r/3);

    % Axes
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(-\r/5,-\r/3) node[below] (x1) {$x$};
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(\r,0) node[right] (x2) {$y$};
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(0,\r) node[above] (x3) {$z$};

    %Angles
    \pic [draw=gray,text=gray,->,"$\phi$"] {angle = x1--orig--phi};
    \pic [draw=gray,text=gray,<-,"$\theta$"] {angle = a--orig--x3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible in `TikZ`?

Comment: Have a look at the `animate` package.

Comment: Here are some examples: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/

Comment: And here's an interesting article: https://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/sunol/

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks, I will have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\makeatletter
\def\@anim@@newframe{\@ifstar\@anim@newframe\@anim@newframe}
\def\@anim@newframe{\end{preview}\begin{preview}}
\renewenvironment{animateinline}[2][]{%
  \let\newframe\@anim@@newframe%
  \let\multiframe\@anim@multiframe%
  \begin{preview}}{%
  \end{preview}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
\multiframe{21}{i=0+1}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{-4*\i}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Define radius
    \def\r{3}

    % Bloch vector
    \coordinate[label=above:$\vec{a}$] (a) at (\myangle:{\r} and {\r/3});
    \coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
    \draw (orig) circle(0.1);
    \draw[-latex] (orig) -- (a);

    % Sphere
    \draw (orig) circle (\r);
    \draw[dashed] (orig) ellipse (\r{} and \r/3);

    % Axes
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(-\r/5,-\r/3) node[below] (x1) {$x$};
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(\r,0) node[right] (x2) {$y$};
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(0,\r) node[above] (x3) {$z$};

    %Angles
    \pic [draw=gray,text=gray,->,"$\phi$"] {angle = x1--orig--a};
    \pic [draw=gray,text=gray,<-,"$\theta$"] {angle = a--orig--x3};

\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to rotate it over the full plane, use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\makeatletter
\def\@anim@@newframe{\@ifstar\@anim@newframe\@anim@newframe}
\def\@anim@newframe{\end{preview}\begin{preview}}
\renewenvironment{animateinline}[2][]{%
  \let\newframe\@anim@@newframe%
  \let\multiframe\@anim@multiframe%
  \begin{preview}}{%
  \end{preview}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
\multiframe{91}{i=0+1}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{-4*\i}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Define radius
    \def\r{3}

    % Bloch vector
    \coordinate[label={\myangle+90}:$\vec{a}$] (a) at (\myangle:{\r} and {\r/3});
    \coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
    \draw (orig) circle(0.1);
    \draw[-latex] (orig) -- (a);

    % Sphere
    \draw (orig) circle (\r);
    \draw[dashed] (orig) ellipse (\r{} and \r/3);

    % Axes
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(-\r/5,-\r/3) node[below] (x1) {$x$};
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(\r,0) node[right] (x2) {$y$};
    \draw[->] (orig) -- ++(0,\r) node[above] (x3) {$z$};

    %Angles
    \pic [draw=gray,text=gray,->,"$\phi$"] {angle = x1--orig--a};
    \pic [draw=gray,text=gray,<-,"$\theta$"] {angle = a--orig--x3};

\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that my code is for exporting the animation. If you do not want to export it, but just incorporate it in your pdf document, comment out the block

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\makeatletter
\def\@anim@@newframe{\@ifstar\@anim@newframe\@anim@newframe}
\def\@anim@newframe{\end{preview}\begin{preview}}
\renewenvironment{animateinline}[2][]{%
  \let\newframe\@anim@@newframe%
  \let\multiframe\@anim@multiframe%
  \begin{preview}}{%
  \end{preview}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The animation will then show on selected viewers such as acroread.

Comment: +1 Especially the linked question is amazing :)

Comment: If possible should be given bounties. Mny thanks, is there a way to rotate vector to whole plane?

Comment: @marmot In my case the animation is not working? Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: @Shamina I animated my answer, you need to comment out a part if you want to have the animation in the pdf file.