# movie creation using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I would like to create a movie using tikz images, but it seems a lot of work without some sort of automation.
I have a background mesh of triangles, and a red line crossing them. At each of the intersection points I would like to raise a pyramidal function (one for each of the 6 intersection points, and each happening one after another sequentially). As each of these functions raise, I would also like to rotate the viewpoint the pyramidal functions can be seen clearly. So far this is what I have:

```
\documentclass[border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, backgrounds,intersections,shapes.arrows}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
        colormap/viridis,
        axis lines*=left,
        zmin=0,zmax=1,
%       view={-45}{45},
        axis line style={draw=none},
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        ]

\def\triangleParamX{s)}
\def\triangleParamY{t*(1-s)}

% draw mesh
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (1,1,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,0,0) (2,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,1,0) (1,1,0)};

\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,2,0) (0,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,1,0) (1,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,1,0) (2,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(2,1,0) (2,2,0) (1,2,0)};

% draw curve with nodes
\addplot3+[BrickRed, solid, thick, no markers, samples=51, samples y=0,domain=0:2,variable=\t]
                                      ({\t)},{sin(\t r)+0.5},{0})
node (A) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.,scale=0.5]{}
node (B) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.15,scale=0.5]{} 
node (C) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.31,scale=0.5]{} 
node (D) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.56,scale=0.5]{} 
node (E) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.785,scale=0.5]{} 
node (F) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=1.,scale=0.5]{} 
;


% draw functions
\newcommand \wen {0.2};

% psi1
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0.5,\wen) (1,0,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wen) (1,0,0) (0.25,0.75,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wen) (0.25,0.75,0) (0,1,0)  };

% psi2
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wen) (0.5,1,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wen) (0,0.5,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,0) (0.25,0.75,\wen) (0,0,0)  };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.25,0.75,\wen) (1,0,0)  };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.5,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wen) (1,0,0)  };

% psi3
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.5,1.,\wen) (0.25,0.75,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.25,0.75,0) (0.5,1.,\wen) (1.,0,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,0.,0) (0.5,1.,\wen) (1.,1.,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (0.5,1.,\wen) (1.,1.35,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.35,0) (0.5,1.,\wen) (1.,2.,0)};
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (0.5,1.,\wen) (0.,1.,0)};

% psi4
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wen) (0.5,1,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wen) (2.,1,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wen) (1.5,1.5,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (1.,1.35,\wen) (1,2,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,2,0) (1.,1.35,\wen) (0.,1.,0)  };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.,1.,0) (1.,1.35,\wen) (0.5,1,0) };


% psi5
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1.35,0) (1.5,1.5,\wen) (1.,1.,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wen) (2,1.,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wen) (2.,1.4,0)  };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2.,1.4,0) (1.5,1.5,\wen) (2,2.,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,2.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wen) (1.,2,0) };
%\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (1.5,1.5,\wen)(1,1.35,0) };

% psi6
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (2.,1.4,\wen) (2.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2.,2.,0) (2.,1.4,\wen) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (2.,1.4,\wen) (1.5,1.5,0)  };


%\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{1-x-y});

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where I have all the pyramidal functions but I have commented all of them but one. One function looks like this:

[image]

So my questions is mainly how do I get a movie out of this code. Can I do this somehow within the code I wrote or do I have to create several files using some sort of scripting language (perhaps using loops)? How do I handle the view point? Luckily enough I have 6 functions, so if each function raises to its maximum value in 10 increments, that would give me 60 frames (so I could divide a full rotation of the mesh by 60).

**UPDATE**

```
This is the updated code:

\documentclass[border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{tikz}
\standaloneconfig{tikz=true}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, backgrounds,intersections,shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0,...,72}{
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{\i*1.25-45};

 \newcommand \wen {0.1};

\begin{axis}[
        colormap/viridis,
        point meta min=-\wen, point meta max=\wen,
        axis lines*=left,
%       xmin=0,xmax=1,
%       ymin=0,ymax=1,
        zmin=-\wen,zmax=\wen,
%        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        view={\theta}{45}, % You can make the view depend on \i
        axis line style={draw=none},
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        ]

\pgfplotsset{meshstyle/.style={patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.01}}

\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,0,0) (1,1,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,0,0) (2,1,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,1,0) (1,1,0)};

\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(0,2,0) (0,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (1,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (2,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(2,1,0) (2,2,0) (1,2,0)};


% draw curve with nodes
\addplot3+[BrickRed, solid, thick, no markers, samples=51, samples y=0,domain=0:2,variable=\t]
                                      ({\t)},{sin(\t r)+0.5},{0})
node (A) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.,scale=0.5]{}
node (B) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.15,scale=0.5]{} 
node (C) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.31,scale=0.5]{} 
node (D) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.56,scale=0.5]{} 
node (E) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.785,scale=0.5]{} 
node (F) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=1.,scale=0.5]{} 
;




% draw functions

% draw weak enrichments

 \pgfplotsset{psistyle/.style={patch, patch type=triangle, ultra thin, shader=faceted interp, fill opacity=0.4}}

% psi1
\ifnum\i>0
\ifnum\i<11
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenOne}{min(\i,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0) (0.25,0.75,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (0.25,0.75,0) (0,1,0) };

\else

\ifnum\i<21

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenOne}{max(20-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0) (0.25,0.75,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (0.25,0.75,0) (0,1,0) };
\fi
\fi
\fi


% psi2
\ifnum\i>10
\ifnum\i<21

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenTwo}{min(\i-10,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0.5,1,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0.5,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.5,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };


\else

\ifnum\i<31

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenTwo}{max(30-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0.5,1,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0.5,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.5,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\fi
\fi
\fi


% psi3
\ifnum\i>20
\ifnum\i<31

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenThree}{min(\i-20,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.25,0.75,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.25,0.75,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,0.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.35,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.35,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,2.,0)};

\else

\ifnum\i<41

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenThree}{max(40-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.25,0.75,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.25,0.75,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,0.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.35,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.35,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,2.,0)};
\fi
\fi
\fi



% psi4
\ifnum\i>30
\ifnum\i<41

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFour}{min(\i-30,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,2,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.,1.,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (2.,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1.5,1.5,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.,1.,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };

\else

\ifnum\i<51

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFour}{max(50-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,2,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.,1.,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (2.,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1.5,1.5,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.,1.,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\fi
\fi
\fi


% psi5
\ifnum\i>40
\ifnum\i<51

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFive}{min(\i-40,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,2.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1.35,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2.,1.4,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,1.4,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,2.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive)(1,1.35,0) };


\else

\ifnum\i<61

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFive}{max(60-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,2.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1.35,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2.,1.4,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,1.4,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,2.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive)(1,1.35,0) };

\fi
\fi
\fi



% psi6
\ifnum\i>50
\ifnum\i<61

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{min(\i-50,10)*\wen/10};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{min(\i-50,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,2.,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (2.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.5,1.5,0)  };


\else

\ifnum\i<71

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{max(70-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,2.,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (2.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.5,1.5,0)  };

\fi
\fi
\fi


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

} % \foreach

\end{document}
```

I have a few issues still I don't know how to resolve:

- The transition between each frame is not smooth. The width each frame is also changing so it's not constant. In particular, halfway through the animation there's a big jump. There must be a way to specify the outer dimensions of the 3-D object I want to visualize so that the center of the mesh is always centered. Is this possible?
- I do not know how to convert the resulting pdf file to an animated gif. I tried using `convert`, following directions [found here](http://phyletica.org/imagemagick/), but at some point the gif couldn't get created giving error `convert: images are not the same size`slide-00.png' @ error/layer.c/OptimizeLayerFrames/964.` I assume this error is given because of my previous remark. Also, whatever gif file created had all frames superposing one another.

Comment: The `animate` package allows you to create pdf animations, and Alex G's [method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799) can be used to create animated gifs. Which output format are you after?

Comment: It could be in any format, but I wanted to use tikz to draw each of the frames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER**: (after clarifications in the comments): With growing functions and changing viewing angle.

```
\documentclass[border={10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{tikz}
\standaloneconfig{tikz=true}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, backgrounds,intersections,shapes.arrows}


\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,...,60}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        colormap/viridis,
        axis lines*=left,
        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        view={\i}{45}, % You can make the view depend on \i
        axis line style={draw=none},
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        ]

\def\triangleParamX{s)}
\def\triangleParamY{t*(1-s)}

% draw mesh
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (1,1,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,0,0) (2,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,1,0) (1,1,0)};

\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,2,0) (0,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,1,0) (1,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,1,0) (2,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(2,1,0) (2,2,0) (1,2,0)};

% draw curve with nodes
\addplot3+[BrickRed, solid, thick, no markers, samples=51, samples y=0,domain=0:2,variable=\t]
                                      ({\t)},{sin(\t r)+0.5},{0})
node (A) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.,scale=0.5]{}
node (B) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.15,scale=0.5]{} 
node (C) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.31,scale=0.5]{} 
node (D) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.56,scale=0.5]{} 
node (E) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.785,scale=0.5]{} 
node (F) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=1.,scale=0.5]{} 
;


% draw functions



% psi1
\ifnum\i>0
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenOne}{min(\i,10)*0.05/10};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0) (0.25,0.75,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (0.25,0.75,0) (0,1,0)  };
\fi

% psi2
\ifnum\i>10
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenTwo}{min(\i-10,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0.5,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0.5,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.5,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\fi
% \ifnum\i>3

% psi3
\ifnum\i>20
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenThree}{min(\i-20,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.25,0.75,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.25,0.75,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,0,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,0.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.35,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.35,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,2.,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.,1.,0)};
\fi

% psi4
\ifnum\i>30
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFour}{min(\i-30,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (2.,1,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1.5,1.5,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1,2,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,2,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.,1.,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.,1.,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\fi

% psi5
\ifnum\i>40
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFive}{min(\i-40,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1.35,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,1.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2.,1.4,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2.,1.4,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,2.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,2.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive)(1,1.35,0) };
\fi

% psi6
\ifnum\i>50
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{min(\i-50,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (2.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2.,2.,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.5,1.5,0)  };
%\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{1-x-y});
\fi
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For fun: a beamer version. (Modulo xcolor...)

\documentclass[xcolor]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\definecolor{BrickRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.06,0.06} % #880000

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A growing plot}
\newcount\myangle
\animate<2-62> 
\animatevalue<2-62>{\myangle}{0}{60} 
\typeout{\myangle}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\i}{\myangle}
\transduration<2-62>{0.4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
        colormap/viridis,
        axis lines*=left,
        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        view={\i}{45}, % You can make the view depend on \i
        axis line style={draw=none},
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        ]

\def\triangleParamX{s)}
\def\triangleParamY{t*(1-s)}

%\addplot3 ({cos(2*pi*x)*cos(2*pi*y)},{cos(2*pi*x)*sin(2*pi*x)},{sin(2*pi*x)});

% draw mesh
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (1,1,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,0,0) (2,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,1,0) (1,1,0)};

\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,2,0) (0,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(0,1,0) (1,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(1,1,0) (2,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1] coordinates {(2,1,0) (2,2,0) (1,2,0)};

% draw curve with nodes
\addplot3+[BrickRed, solid, thick, no markers, samples=51, samples y=0,domain=0:2,variable=\t]
                                      ({\t)},{sin(\t r)+0.5},{0})
node (A) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.,scale=0.5]{}
node (B) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.15,scale=0.5]{} 
node (C) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.31,scale=0.5]{} 
node (D) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.56,scale=0.5]{} 
node (E) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.785,scale=0.5]{} 
node (F) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=1.,scale=0.5]{} 
;


% draw functions


% psi1
\ifnum\i>0
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenOne}{min(\i,10)*0.05/10};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0) (0.25,0.75,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (0.25,0.75,0) (0,1,0)  };
\fi

% psi2
\ifnum\i>10
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenTwo}{min(\i-10,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0.5,1,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0.5,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0.5,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.5,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\fi
% \ifnum\i>3

% psi3
\ifnum\i>20
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenThree}{min(\i-20,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.25,0.75,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.25,0.75,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,0,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,0.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.35,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.35,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,2.,0)};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.,1.,0)};
\fi

% psi4
\ifnum\i>30
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFour}{min(\i-30,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (2.,1,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1.5,1.5,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1,2,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,2,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.,1.,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(0.,1.,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\fi

% psi5
\ifnum\i>40
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFive}{min(\i-40,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1,1.35,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,1.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2.,1.4,0)  };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2.,1.4,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,2.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2,2.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive)(1,1.35,0) };
\fi

% psi6
\ifnum\i>50
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{min(\i-50,10)*0.05};
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (2.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(2.,2.,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[patch,dotted,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.1, shader=faceted interp] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.5,1.5,0)  };
%\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1,y domain=0:1] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{1-x-y});
\fi

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: As for the additional request, consider

```
\documentclass[border={1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt}]{standalone} % I made the border smaller
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{tikz}
\standaloneconfig{tikz=true}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, backgrounds,intersections,shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0,...,72}{
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{\i*1.25-45};

\newcommand\wen{0.1} % <- no ; here

\begin{axis}[
        colormap/viridis,
        point meta min=-\wen, point meta max=\wen,
        axis lines*=left,
%       xmin=0,xmax=1,
%       ymin=0,ymax=1,
        zmin=-\wen,zmax=\wen,
%        zmin=0,zmax=1,
        view={\theta}{45}, % 
        axis line style={draw=none},
        tick style={draw=none},
        ticks=none,
        ]

\pgfplotsset{meshstyle/.style={patch,patch type=triangle,color=gray,faceted color=gray,fill opacity=0.01}}

\addplot3[draw=none,domain=0:360] ({1+2*cos(x)},{1+2*sin(x)},0);
\addplot3[draw=none,domain=0:3] (0,0,x);

\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,0,0) (1,1,0) (0,1,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,0,0) (2,1,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,0,0) (2,1,0) (1,1,0)};

\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(0,2,0) (0,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (1,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (2,1,0) (1,2,0)};
\addplot3[meshstyle] coordinates {(2,1,0) (2,2,0) (1,2,0)};


% draw curve with nodes
\addplot3+[BrickRed, solid, thick, no markers, samples=51, samples y=0,domain=0:2,variable=\t]
                                      ({\t)},{sin(\t r)+0.5},{0})
node (A) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.,scale=0.5]{}
node (B) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.15,scale=0.5]{} 
node (C) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.31,scale=0.5]{} 
node (D) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.56,scale=0.5]{} 
node (E) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=0.785,scale=0.5]{} 
node (F) [draw, circle,fill=white,pos=1.,scale=0.5]{} 
;




% draw functions

% draw weak enrichments

 \pgfplotsset{psistyle/.style={patch, patch type=triangle, ultra thin, shader=faceted interp, fill opacity=0.4}}

% psi1
\ifnum\i>0
\ifnum\i<11
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenOne}{min(\i,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0) (0.25,0.75,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (0.25,0.75,0) (0,1,0) };

\else

\ifnum\i<21

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenOne}{max(20-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (1,0,0) (0.25,0.75,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,\wenOne) (0.25,0.75,0) (0,1,0) };
\fi
\fi
\fi


% psi2
\ifnum\i>10
\ifnum\i<21

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenTwo}{min(\i-10,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0.5,1,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0.5,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.5,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };


\else

\ifnum\i<31

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenTwo}{max(30-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0.5,1,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0.5,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0.5,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (0,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.5,1,0) (0.25,0.75,\wenTwo) (1,0,0)  };
\fi
\fi
\fi


% psi3
\ifnum\i>20
\ifnum\i<31

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenThree}{min(\i-20,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.25,0.75,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.25,0.75,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,0.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.35,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.35,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,2.,0)};

\else

\ifnum\i<41

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenThree}{max(40-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (0.25,0.75,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.25,0.75,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,0,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,0.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,1.35,0)};
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.35,0) (0.5,1.,\wenThree) (1.,2.,0)};
\fi
\fi
\fi



% psi4
\ifnum\i>30
\ifnum\i<41

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFour}{min(\i-30,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,2,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.,1.,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (2.,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1.5,1.5,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.,1.,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };

\else

\ifnum\i<51

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFour}{max(50-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,2,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.,1.,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (2.,1,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1.5,1.5,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (1,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(0.,1.,0) (1.,1.35,\wenFour) (0.5,1,0) };
\fi
\fi
\fi


% psi5
\ifnum\i>40
\ifnum\i<51

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFive}{min(\i-40,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,2.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1.35,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2.,1.4,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,1.4,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,2.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive)(1,1.35,0) };


\else

\ifnum\i<61

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenFive}{max(60-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,2.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1,1.35,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (1.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2,1.,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2.,1.4,0)  };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,1.4,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive) (2,2.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (1.5,1.5,\wenFive)(1,1.35,0) };

\fi
\fi
\fi



% psi6
\ifnum\i>50
\ifnum\i<61

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{min(\i-50,10)*\wen/10};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{min(\i-50,10)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,2.,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (2.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.5,1.5,0)  };


\else

\ifnum\i<71

\pgfmathsetmacro{\wenSix}{max(70-\i,0)*\wen/10};

\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(2.,2.,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.,2,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.5,1.5,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (2.,1.,0) };
\addplot3[psistyle] coordinates {(1.,2,0) (2.,1.4,\wenSix) (1.5,1.5,0)  };

\fi
\fi
\fi


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

} % \foreach

\end{document}
```

with `convert -density 120 -delay 50 -loop 0 -alpha remove tex.pdf ani.gif` you'll get

[image]

Comment: Will this create a single .pdf file that I have to convert to a movie? In each of your frames functions raise immediately, but I would scale them from 0 to their maximum value in 10 frames. Then I would continue with the next one (while the former goes down), and so on. So if you see, it would require 60 frames total to raise all pyramids. I thought about the view point, and since it would require 60 frames, I could divide an entire rotation of the mesh (360 degrees) by 60, so each frame every 6 degrees, so it would be `view={\theta}{45}` where `\theta` is the actual view angle.

Comment: @aaragon I still do not now your desired output format. At this point, this creates a bunch of pdf frames, that can be converted to a gif movie, say. You are using pgfplots, which is very powerful, but there are expansion issues that prevented me from using the animate package in a straightforward way. (I am not saying it cannot be done but my first attempt was not successful.) The increment can be done in a straightforward way, wait a few minutes, I'll do that. But as long as I don't know where the journey should go I won't put too much effort into it.

Comment: @aaragon I updated my answer.

Comment: @marmot Wonderful, excellent code. Very very good. +1.

Comment: I will try to take it from there and post an update with the result. I think I can manage to do everything else. If I wanted to embed the movie within a beamer presentation, what would be the best output? One more question: I see your mesh is somehow going down. Is there a way to avoid that by having the mesh always centered?

Comment: @aaragon Beamer comes with its own animation facilities. You will essentially have to do `\animate<2-62>
\animatevalue<2-62>{\i}{0}{60}
\transduration<2-62>{0.4}` or something along those lines. As for the axis, there are many options to control things. One option is to draw a bulky plot, e.g. a sphere, with `draw=none` that is so large that the size changes of the other elements and the rotations do not matter.

Comment: @aaragon I added a beamer version.

Comment: @marmot I have updated my questions. I still have a couple of things to resolve so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @aaragon I am confused. You said it should be a beamer code. Why is "your" new code using the standalone class? And note that I am not supposed to answer follow-up questions in the same question. However, if you make a *final* request, I will look at it later that day.

Comment: This movie will be embedded in a beamer presentation (it's not a beamer document), so I'm not sure your beamer solution was appropriate for this. So in the end I decided to create a gif animation for that. If you can help tackle the two bullets in my edited questions it would be great.

Comment: @aaragon I am looking at this now and I find that `convert -density 120 -delay 50 -loop 0 -alpha remove tex.pdf ani.gif` works, what convert options are you using?

Comment: I was using the command line provided in the site `convert -layers OptimizePlus -delay 75 slide-0?.png slide-1[01234].png -delay 300 slide-1[567].png -loop 0 slides.gif`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77892/discussion-between-marmot-and-aaragon).

Comment: Indeed your command works much better.

Comment: @aaragon I updated my answer. All I did is to add two objects with `draw=none` that are a bit larger than the stuff you're plotting. This prevents the jumps. (I still don't get why you do not use the `beamer` package, if you compile the beamer part of my answer and view it with `acroread` you'll get a nice animation....)

Comment: Indeed that removed the jumps between frames. It's a nice animation. The only thing I dislike is the fact that the background mesh changes size towards half the animation because of the perspective. Perhaps this can go away if the white with `draw=none` is a circle that circumscribes the mesh? I'll try the beamer version too. It's just that this animation is supposed to be part of the slide, to which I have to add equations and other stuff. It will take forever to compile the slide, so I'll have to protect it with conditional compilation while I work on the rest of the presentation.

Comment: Actually you had added a circle that circumscribes the mesh already, so I have no clue how to prevent the background mesh from changing size.

Comment: @marmot I checked the beamer version and the file has 2.9MB with the animation only, so I guess this is a no-go.

Comment: @aaragon Yes, but this is merely a consequence of your colormap, which might not be necessary. For instance, if you change to `colormap/blackwhite,` the size will decrease by a factor 3 or so. And *in principle* you could do the same with `tikz-3dplot` or with the `3d` library, which will almost certainly result in a much smaller file and a much shorter compilation time... but this certainly deserves a separate question.