# Displaying circles in sequence from the same central point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw concentric circles that are displayed in sequence.

When applying the following code, the circles appear to move from the top edge downwards as each circle is displayed.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to avoid this and make them displayed on top of each other from the same centre coordinate as in this diagram.

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin {center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
  \only<1,5>
{
\node[circle, outer color=yellow!60!green, inner color=white, minimum width=5cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
\fill[pattern=dots,pattern color = black] (3.6,-.4) -- + +(.8,0) -- ++ (0,.8) -- ++(-.8,0) -- cycle;
}
  \only<4-5>
{
\node[circle, outer color=green!80!purple, inner color=purple, minimum width=4cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
}
  \only<3-5>
{
\node[circle, outer color=purple, inner color=purple!20!red, minimum width=3cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
}
  \only<2-5>
{
\node[circle, outer color=purple, inner color=purple!50!black, minimum width=2cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a rude solution is add to each slide invisible circle with `minimum size` of the greatest one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{Circles \dots}
\begin {center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9,
circ/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{circle,outer color=#1, inner color=#2, minimum width=#3,
                              node contents={}},
                    ]
  \only<1,5>
{
\node[circ=yellow!60!green/white/5cm];
\fill[pattern=dots,pattern color = black] (-0.4,-0.4) rectangle + (0.8,0.8);
}
  \only<4-5>
{
\node[circle, minimum size=5cm] {};
\node[circ=green!80!purple/purple/4cm];
}
  \only<3-5>
{
\node[circle, minimum size=5cm] {};
\node[circ=purple/purple!20!red/3cm];
}
  \only<2-5>
{
\node[circle, minimum size=5cm] {};
\node[circ=purple/purple!50!black/2cm];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

note:

- coordinates in `tikzpicure` are relative to picture, not to slide. therefore in your case `at (4,0)` gives the same result as `at (0,0)` or if you omit explicit notation of coordinates.
- for determining coordinate on absolute position on slide, you need to use `remember picture, overlay`:

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, fadings, patterns,
                  overlay-beamer-styles}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile,t]
  \frametitle{Circles \dots}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
  circ/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{circle,outer color=#1, inner color=#2, minimum width=#3},
                      ]
    \only<1,5>
  {
  \node[circ=yellow!60!green/white/5cm] (center) at (current page.center) {};
  \fill[pattern=dots,pattern color = black]
      ($(current page.center)+(-0.4,-0.4)$) rectangle + (0.8,0.8);
  }
    \only<4-5>
  {
  \node[circ=green!80!purple/purple/4cm] at (center) {};
  }
    \only<3-5>
  {
  \node[circ=purple/purple!20!red/3cm] at (center) {};;
  }
    \only<2-5>
  {
  \node[circ=purple/purple!50!black/2cm] at (center) {};;
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1. Very good the answer and the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just one more comment please. How to use remember picture, overlay in your code to make the drawings centered vertically and horizontally on the slides.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much! now i succeed to finish answer.

Comment: @Hany, see edited answer. i had problems with uploading image so i provide complete answer in more steps. sorry for any  inconvenience.

Answer (score 12):

A less rude solution with the `beamer-overlay-styles` library.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} %<-added
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{Circles with the \texttt{overlay-beamer-styles} library}
\begin {center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\node[visible on=<{1,5}>,circle, outer color=yellow!60!green, inner color=white, minimum width=5cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
\fill[visible on=<{1,5}>,pattern=dots,pattern color = black] (3.6,-.4) -- + +(.8,0) -- ++ (0,.8) -- ++(-.8,0) -- cycle;
\node[visible on=<{4-5}>,circle, outer color=green!80!purple, inner color=purple, minimum width=4cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
\node[visible on=<{3-5}>,circle, outer color=purple, inner color=purple!20!red, minimum width=3cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
\node[visible on=<{2-5}>,circle, outer color=purple, inner color=purple!50!black, minimum width=2cm] (radial) at (4,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The \usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} is not recognized!!!

Comment: @Hany What do you mean by "not recognized"? It is part of the standard TeX distributions. If you installed a smaller version, perhaps you need to install it with your package manager. And you can also find it [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz?lang=en). This library is taylor-made for your problem, I think.

Comment: @marmot, how you manage to provide "animation" of slides. (showing sequence of them as at presentation}. i sow may your answers with this "trick" and sometimes (as at this question) this is very useful. i like to learn it :-) +1 for it!

Comment: @Zarko I use the conversion chain of [this nice answer by AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799) ;-)

Comment: @marmot, thank you for info. i  will try it asap!

Comment: I am using miktex portable, I downloaded the style you provided the link for, and it still is not recognized.

Comment: @Hany Did you *install* it with some package manager or just download? In the latter case you may need to copy the TeX file `tikzlibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex` in the same directory as the main file. However, the cleaner way is to install.

Comment: I downloaded the tikzlibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex, and it works now very fine. Thank you very much for your answer.