# How to rotate a 3d-plot figure of PStricks like as Asymptote?

Tags: pstricks

An example in 3d-plot.pdf

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(4,6)
\psset{Beta=60}
\pstThreeDCoor[zMax=9]
\psCylinder[RotX=10,increment=5]{3}{5}
\pstThreeDLine[linecolor=red](0,0,0)(0,0,8.5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image]

An example of Asymptote:

[image]

Question:

Can PStricks do it? ... !

Comment: These interactive 3D objects are Adobe PRC files that only Asymptote (as an open-source software) is able to write. They are embedded into PDF using the `media9` LaTeX package under the hood. Only Acrobat (Reader) is currently able to render them as embedded objects in a PDF file.

Comment: @AlexG I like more PStricks than and hope in the future, these interactive 3D will be embedded into PStricks..... Because Asymptote is too difficult that I can not understand it. Sob.

Comment: This is unlikely to happen, I am afraid. PRC is a binary format, which is difficult to write from within Postscript.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "Can PStricks do it"? . 3D objects in central projection or the style of such figures?

Comment: @AlexG The news came as a complete shock........

Comment: @herbert : I guess OP means interactivity.

Comment: @AlexG yes, interactivity is the biggest thing compare to rotate in three-dimension...

Comment: Rotating as a 3d Object (as Aleander already mentioned) is not possible, but as a simple animation rotation it s no problem.

Comment: @herbert I am going to prepare one.

Comment: @Herbert " but as a simple animation rotation it s no problem ". Can you show it for me, please!

Comment: Gradient shading with Asymptote is really awesome. Unfortunately, it cannot be reproduced with PSTricks.

Comment: @chishimotoji: run `texdoc animate` (the package from Alexander) or see http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Animation/gif/gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These interactive 3D objects are Adobe PRC files that only Asymptote (as an open-source software) is able to write. They are embedded into PDF using the `media9 LaTeX` package under the hood. Only Acrobat (Reader) is currently able to render them as embedded objects in a PDF file.

As PRC is a binary format, it is difficult to write it from within a PostScript program. With PSTricks, it is possible to prepare frame-based animations as standalone (GIF, SVG) files or embedded into PDF.

Click on the image to load the animated SVG. Chrome, Chromium or other Blink-based browser required, as Firefox is too slow:

[image]

```
%\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}   % PDF animation in A-Reader
%\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=5pt,export]{standalone}  % for export to animated GIF
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{article} %animated SVG
\usepackage{animate}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\frame{\begin{animateinline}[controls]{24}
  \multiframe{72}{iAng=0+5}{
    \begin{pspicture}(-4.9,-3.6)(4.6,6)
    \psset{Alpha=\iAng,Beta=60}
    \pstThreeDCoor[zMax=9]
    \psCylinder[RotX=10,increment=5]{3}{5}
    \pstThreeDLine[linecolor=red](0,0,0)(0,0,8.5)
    \end{pspicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with consecutive?

Comment: use the correct button!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood of gif. I want it seems gif INTO PDF. How to do that?

Comment: Uncomment 1st line, comment out the 3rd. But is not GIF, it is better ;-). But you need A-Reader to view the PDF.

Comment: Hi, can your answer be used \multido to replace \multiframe ? If it works , please give me its code!

Comment: What do you want to achieve by replacing  multiframe?

Comment: I saw many simple examples without animateinline environment and animate package. They only use \multido or \foreach and the code works fine. So, I want to know in your answer, can we?

Comment: You wil not get an animation then. Only a PDF with many pages.

Comment: Wow, I see ah. I understood.

Comment: The same result (multipage PDF) you will get if you comment out the third code line and enable the second one with the `export` option. If you want an animated GIF, you have to convert the multipage PDF, e. g. with ImageMagick `convert`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136666).