# Creating GIF files in beamer questions

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

Many posts here show animated graphics to illustrate solutions about content uncovering. How can I get GIF file for my slides to upload?

Comment: Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799 ?

Comment: No. I think the question needs to be edited. I did not mean to get a PDF with an animated content. I mean how to capture multiple successive frames from a beamer PDF and save them as GIF

Comment: Yes, that is what tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799  explains at the very end: `convert -density 300 -delay 4 -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif`.