# Pointing an arrow to an entry in a table (beamer)

Tags: tables, beamer, tikzmark, annotations

I am trying to annotate a single entry in a table on a slide. My problem is that the word "tag" appears at a correct y location, but its x location is dead center of the slide. I tried `xshift = ???` lots of values, but it simply wouldn't budge. I adapted the code for arrow from an answer by @Gonzalo Medina, but I have clearly made some fundamental errors in the integration, due to which I don't quite get what I want. To clarify again, I'd like more control on the word "tag", so that it positions nicely closer (in x axis) to the word "diverse", as that's what it's annotating. Additionally, I'd like it if I can enclose "tag" in a little `tcolorbox`. Thank you!

I want to add that I originally had a more minimal version of this code (with only the packages I need for *this* slide) that worked as desired; however, when integrated with the rest of my presentation (which has all the packages in the code below), I get this bug of wrong position. So it's some package interaction bug.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%% packages I am adding
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio! 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing, patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}
\usepackage{skull}

\usepackage{nccmath} %for \medmath command to fit long eqns in tcolorbox
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}


%\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}

%% start1
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\tikzset{rowhl/.style={
    set fill color = white, 
    set border color = red, 
    above left offset={-0.01,0.37},
    below right offset={0.1,-0.09},
    },}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cost}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Team}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Features}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-6} 
\thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}initial \\ cost \end{tabular}} & \thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}secondary \\ cost \end{tabular}} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{scale}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{impact}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}diverse\tikzmark{B}\\ selection \end{tabular}}}\\
\midrule
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $y1$ & $y2$ & name 1 + name 2 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark\\
    \tikzmarkin<2->[rowhl]{aa} $z1$ &  $z2$ & name 1 + name 2  +name 3 + name 4 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \tikzmarkend{aa} \\
        $v1$  & $v2$ & name 5 + name 8 + name 9 &  & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
        $w1$  & $w2$ & name 1 + name 3 + name 5 & \checkmark & \checkmark &  \\
             $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [right=5cm,above=6cm,minimum width=0pt] at (pic cs:b) (B) {tag};
  \draw [<-,out=5,in=180] ([xshift=140pt, yshift=115pt]{pic cs:b}) to (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{teams and costs}
    \label{MyTable}
    \vspace{-4mm}
\end{table} 
%%%%%%%%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. You rescale the table "from outside". This destroys the node location mechanism of `tikz`/`tikzmark`. In general, when you use something like `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` on a `tikzpicture` with `remember picture`, the remembered coordinate positions will be off. The only way this can conceivably work is to make the `overlay` picture part of the `\resizebox`. Even then one can construct cases in which this fails, but here this is a possibility.
2. I also cannot see a tikz mark of name `b`. But you probably want a `\tikzmarknode` anyway.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%% packages I am adding
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio! 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing, patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}
\usepackage{skull}

\usepackage{nccmath} %for \medmath command to fit long eqns in tcolorbox
% \usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
% \tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % gets loaded by beamer and tikz
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}


%\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}

%% start1
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\tikzset{rowhl/.style={
    set fill color = white, 
    set border color = red, 
    above left offset={-0.01,0.37},
    below right offset={0.1,-0.09},
    },}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cost}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Team}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Features}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-6} 
\thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}initial \\ cost \end{tabular}} & \thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}secondary \\ cost \end{tabular}} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{scale}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{impact}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\tikzmarknode{b}{diverse}\\ selection \end{tabular}}}\\
\midrule
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $y1$ & $y2$ & name 1 + name 2 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark\\
    \tikzmarkin<2->[rowhl]{aa} $z1$ &  $z2$ & name 1 + name 2  +name 3 + name 4 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \tikzmarkend{aa} \\
        $v1$  & $v2$ & name 5 + name 8 + name 9 &  & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
        $w1$  & $w2$ & name 1 + name 3 + name 5 & \checkmark & \checkmark &  \\
             $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [right=0.5cm,above=2cm,minimum width=0pt]  (B) at (b)  {tag};
  \draw [stealth-,out=5,in=180] (b) to (B);
\end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{teams and costs}
    \label{MyTable}
    \vspace{-4mm}
\end{table} 
%%%%%%%%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Schrodinger's cat! I found another fix as well. Thank you for teaching me about the subtlety of using ```resizebox``` with ```rememeber picture```. Very simple fix, just changing the positioning of ```}```! Is there a difference between ```tikzmark``` and ```tikzmarknode```?

Comment: @lazulikid I had already upvoted your post. ;-) Yes, there is a huge difference. `\tikzmark{<id>}` only sets a coordinate mark. `\tikzmarknode{<id>}{<content>}` makes `<content>` a node (with all sorts of nice checks which mode you are in), so you have access to all the anchors of the *node* (as opposed to coordinate).

Comment: Thank you! I have one final meta question. How does one get to display the output here  in an answer, like you have done above? (As in, show the slide with the animation of the encircled row.

Comment: @lazulikid I am using `convert` as shown at the end of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/194703). For this animation I was using `density 300` and `delay 144`.

Comment: I hope it's ok to have a question about this -- with this code (as well as with mine below), I find that I simply can't move the "tag" to the left or right. It only goes up and down. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @lazulikid Use `\node [minimum width=0pt]  (B)  at ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=2cm]b)  {tag};` If you change the value of `xshift`, you can move the node to the left or right.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Schrodinger's cat's answer, but I found another solution simultaneously (for the first time!) that I am proud of, and hence I'll post mine here as well.

I changed the way I was defining position, by using `below left` in relation to `current page.north east`. Code below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%% packages I am adding
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio! 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing, patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,tikzmark}
\usepackage{skull}

\usepackage{nccmath} %for \medmath command to fit long eqns in tcolorbox
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}


%\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture, overlay]

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}

%% start1
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\tikzset{rowhl/.style={
    set fill color = white, 
    set border color = red, 
    above left offset={-0.01,0.37},
    below right offset={0.1,-0.09},
    },}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cost}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Team}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Features}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-6} 
\thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}initial \\ cost \end{tabular}} & \thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}secondary \\ cost \end{tabular}} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{scale}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{impact}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}diverse\tikzmark{B}\\ selection \end{tabular}}}\\
\midrule
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $y1$ & $y2$ & name 1 + name 2 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark\\
    \tikzmarkin<2->[rowhl]{aa} $z1$ &  $z2$ & name 1 + name 2  +name 3 + name 4 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \tikzmarkend{aa} \\
        $v1$  & $v2$ & name 5 + name 8 + name 9 &  & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
        $w1$  & $w2$ & name 1 + name 3 + name 5 & \checkmark & \checkmark &  \\
             $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
     $x1$ & $x2$ & name 1 + name 2 + name 3 &  & \checkmark &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, 
    tabletag/.style = {
                rounded corners, 
            draw = blue,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=1pt,
            align = center
            }] 
  \node  at (pic cs:b) (B) [below left= 1 cm and 2 cm of current page.north east, style = tabletag] {tag};
  \draw [<-,out=5,in=0] ([xshift=140pt, yshift=115pt]{pic cs:b}) to (B.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{teams and costs}
    \label{MyTable}
    \vspace{-4mm}
\end{table} 
%%%%%%%%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```