# Tangent vector to curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[view={120}{20},
                height = 4in,width=4in,
                axis lines=center,axis on top,
              no marks,axis equal,
                xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,zmin=-1.5,zmax=1.5,
             enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
                    \addplot3+[color = blue, thick, no markers,samples=250, samples y=0,domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t, decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 0.01 and .999 step 2em with {\arrow [scale=1]{stealth}}
    }, postaction=decorate]({sin(\t r)},{sin(2*\t r)},{sin(3*\t r)});
                    \draw[color = red, very thick,-latex] ({sin(3 r)}, {sin(6 r)}, {sin(9 r)}) -- ++({cos(3 r)}, {2*cos(6 r)}, {3*cos(9 r)});
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Plot:

[image]

How to properly draw a line tangent to the curve at t = 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already placing tons of tangent arrow heads, so you can use the same strategy to place a complete arrow in a second `postaction`. Since `t` runs from `0` to `2pi` and you want to place the arrow at `t=2`, the position is `1/pi`. Please note that it is important to use coordinates with units, i.e.

```
\draw[color = red, very thick,-latex]  (-0.5cm,0cm) -- (0.5cm,0cm);
```

to have the arrow parallel since otherwise you will be using a coordinate system installed by `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[view={120}{20},
                height = 4in,width=4in,
                axis lines=center,axis on top,
              no marks,axis equal,
                xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,zmin=-1.5,zmax=1.5,
             enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
    \addplot3+[color = blue, thick, no markers,samples=250, samples y=0,domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t, 
    postaction={decorate,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 0.01 and .999 step 2em with {\arrow [scale=1]{stealth}},
    }},
    postaction={decorate,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 1/pi with {
        \draw[color = red, very thick,-latex] 
    (-0.5cm,0cm) -- (0.5cm,0cm);
    }
    }}
    ]({sin(deg(\t))},{sin(deg(2*\t))},{sin(deg(3*\t))});
                    
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can compute the velocity at a given `t`. (In principle you can compute the tangent analytically, too, so this hybrid answer is a bit senseless but this is a LaTeX answer so we let LaTeX find out the slope. We could also let it find out the velocity numerically, perhaps on another day. And of course the position is just an approximation, too.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\foreach \myt in {0.2,0.4,...,6.2}        
{\begin{tikzpicture}        
  \begin{axis}[view={120}{20},
                height = 4in,width=4in,
                axis lines=center,axis on top,
              no marks,axis equal,
                xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,zmin=-1.5,zmax=1.5,
             enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
    \addplot3+[color = blue, thick, no markers,samples=250, samples y=0,domain=0:2*pi,variable=\t, 
    postaction={decorate,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 0.01 and .999 step 2em with {\arrow [scale=1]{stealth}},
    }},
    postaction={decorate,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position {\myt/2/pi} with {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylen}{sqrt(pow(cos(deg(\myt)),2)+pow(2*cos(deg(2*\myt)),2)+pow(3*cos(3*deg(\myt)),2))}
        \draw[color = red, very thick,-latex,overlay] 
    (0cm,0cm) -- (0.5*\mylen*1cm,0cm);
    }
    }}
    ]({sin(deg(\t))},{sin(deg(2*\t))},{sin(deg(3*\t))});
                    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I meant to put at t = 3, and also, I am drawing a velocity vector, so I want to draw it with that magnitude.

Comment: @Superman `t=3` corresponds to `mark=at position 1/pi with`, and the length is just given the components in  `(-0.5cm,0cm) -- (0.5cm,0cm);`. If you want the "real" velocity, you need to compute the time derivative of your curve and take the absolute value, which yields `sqrt(pow(cos(deg(\t)),2)+pow(2*cos(deg(2*\t)),2)+pow(3*cos(3*deg(\t)),2))` in this case.

Comment: So by using `overlay`, you made this into a GIF, right? Out of curiosity, in which viewer is the GIF viewable?

Comment: @Superman No, `overlay` is just to avoid that the bounding box gets altered. As for the viewer, I do not know, certainly on Safari you can see an animation.

Comment: Oh, ok, I think that you made a gif because you set a `\foreach` loop at the beginning of the document. I can see the GIF from the StackExchange app on my iPad.

Comment: @Superman yes, i was using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919 to create the gif.

Comment: Got it. By the way, kind of a silly question, how to put a dot at the beginning of the red tangent line?

Comment: @Superman One way: load also `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` and then use something like `\draw[color = red, very thick,{Circle[length=3pt]}-latex,overlay]  ...`.

Comment: I will have a look at this later.