# TikZ — logarithmic (golden) spiral in a golden rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm almost happy with my golden spiral in golden rectangles:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,class=article,border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{fp}
    \usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=4]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{\w*(2/(1+sqrt(5)))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{(-(\h/(\h-\w))*\w)/((\h/\w)-(\h/(\h-\w)))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{(\h/\w)*\dx}

        \draw (0,0) rectangle (\w,\h);
        \draw (\h,0) -- (\h,\h); 
        \draw (\h,{\w-\h}) -- (\w,{\w-\h});        
        \draw ({2*\w-2*\h)},{\w-\h}) -- ({2*\w-2*\h},\h);      
        \draw (\h,{4*\h-2*\w}) -- ({2*\w-2*\h)},{4*\h-2*\w});
        \draw ({6*\h-3*\w},{4*\h-2*\w}) -- ({6*\h-3*\w},{\w-\h});
        \draw ({6*\h-3*\w},{6*\w-9*\h}) -- ({2*\w-2*\h},{6*\w-9*\h});
        \draw ({2*\w-2*\h-13*\h+8*\w},{4*\h-2*\w}) -- ({2*\w-2*\h-13*\h+8*\w},{4*\h-2*\w-13*\h+8*\w});

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{(-2/pi)*ln((1+sqrt(5))/2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{sqrt(pow(\dx,2) + pow((\dy-\h), 2))}

        \draw[red, rotate around={{-atan((2*\h-\w)/\w)}:(\dx,\dy)}, domain=0:6*pi, variable=\t, samples=300] plot[fixed point arithmetic] ({\dx-\d*exp(\a*\t)*cos(deg(\t))}, {\dy-\d*exp(\a*\t)*sin(deg(\t))});

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

But even with 5000 samples and very thin lines there is a small problem:

[image]

The logarithmic spiral should stay inside the box, but it doesn't.
The spirals [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146556/golden-spiral-in-tikz-how-do-i-get-the-right-shape-and-background) have the same problem as mine. Is there a way to fix this?

The line width is not the problem. It's getting even worse with thinner lines of same width:

[image]

Comment: Is that from the double line width (0.2mm spiral, 0.1mm grid)? Does it vanish if you set the spiral to 0.1mm?

Comment: Please post complete code! Completing your code in the most obvious way, I just get gazillions of errors.

Comment: No, the line width is not the problem.

Comment: I believe this is the correct result: The golden spiral passes through the points that divide the golden rectangles, but it's not tangent to the rectangle borders at these points. Take a look at Fig. 34 in [Spirals and the Golden Section](http://www.emis.de/journals/NNJ/Sharp_v4n1-pt03.html) or see [Golden Rectangle on Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRectangle.html)

Comment: @Jake An answer? (Or is this off-topic as it's about maths, or ...?

Comment: @JosephWright: I was hoping for some feedback from GeMir first

Comment: @Jake you are right, thank you. I just voted "useful" instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: @Torbjørn: I voted to close

Comment: Curve fitting is fundamental to *any* typesetting system. Hard to imagine this being off-topic.

Comment: That the golden spiral is NOT tangent to the squares is a *mathematical* fact. All OP needed is a confirmation that what s/he saw is indeed correct. You don't want to correct a correct behavior of pgf/tikz.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the Fibonacci spiral obtained by drawing quarter-circles inside each of the squares you have drawn: In that case the "spiral" (not really a spiral) will not stray outside the squares. The Golden spiral you have drawn can be thought of as a continuous limit of the discrete Fibonacci "spiral".