# Balloon shape in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to make a balloon-like shape in TikZ? Personally, I haven't found anything closer than an ellipse:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{balloon}=[ball color=red];    
    \shade[balloon] ellipse (2 and 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean an inflatable balloon as opposed to a speech balloon I guess?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is meant as an illustration of a physical experiment involving a helium balloon.

Comment: Everything’s possible but you need to specify the balloon’s path. You can use (ellipsoid) arcs, you can use `to` with specified angles, distances, looseness and such or directly specify a Bézier curve with the `.. controls … ..` operator. — On another node: Do you want to define a PGF shape (that can be used as a node similar to `circle` and `rectangle`) or do you only want to draw/fill a path shaped like a balloon?

Comment: I only need a single drawing of a balloon, that's all... :-)

Comment: I would go with hobby for this with some shading; a weakly related example is: [Draw a closed liquid-droped shaped curve with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73614/13304).

Comment: Even less related to your drawing but a similar example: [How can I draw an egg using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74168)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Without PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{balloon}=[ball color=red];    
    \shade[balloon] ellipse (1.75 and 2);
    \shade[balloon] (-.1,-2) -- (-.3,-2.2) -- (.3,-2.2) -- (.1,-2) -- cycle;
    \draw (0,-2.2) -- (0,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, we can do that with a very simple Bezier curve.  The idea of including a small part below the knot is inspired by the other answer to this question.  The draw command afterwards draws the rope.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[ball color=red] (-.08,-2.2) .. controls (2,0) and (-2,0) .. (.08,-2.2);
  \draw (0,-2.2) -- (0,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the tikz code producing a floating balloon]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I could really have used that ten years ago when I wrote that physics report. 