# plotting a circular-shape in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot the following figure with, e.g., tikz package, but I don't know how to get the colored circular shape. (I am new to this page so apologies if my question is too primitive.)
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation, and find out what the issue is, when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you reduce your image to its useful part?

Comment: @AndréC Everything except the triangle.

Comment: The easiest way I see is with hobby, see for example: [Draw a closed liquid-droped shaped curve with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73614/13304)

Comment: @Teodorism I just wanted to say delete the empty areas above and below your drawing.

Comment: @Teodorism Is this curve defined by an equation, or is it sufficient to draw a curve that approximately resembles it?

Comment: @AndréC It's sufficient to draw a curve that approximately resembles it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

Explanations via comments written in the source code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}% this package is used to build figures
\usetikzlibrary{angles}% this library allows you to easily draw angles and add text to them. It requires these angles to be defined by 3 points with the operations \node or \coordinate. It is not possible to use coordinates such as (0,0). Thus, I defined 4 points named (a), (b), (o) and (d) when building the first path.
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}% this library allows you to fill the path with a repetitive pattern like a mosaic. I used the pattern `north east lines`.

\usepackage{siunitx}% this package defines the macro \ang{} which allows to correctly display angles in degrees.

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}      
\draw (60:3cm)coordinate(a)--(0,0)coordinate(o)--(-60:3cm)coordinate(b);  
% The curve is drawn using 2 bezier curves symmetrical to the horizontal axis. The first starts at `(0,0)` and ends at `(4,0)`. The two points `+(60:2)` and `+(90:2)` are the control points of this Béziers curve. The first control point is `+(60:2)`. The + sign means that its placement is relative to the starting point `(0,0)`. It is placed 2 cm from the starting point at an angle of 60°. The second control point `+(90:2)` is placed relative to the end of the bezier curve `(4,0)`. 
\draw[pattern color=red,pattern=north east lines] (0,0)..controls +(60:2) and +(90:2) .. (4,0)coordinate(d)..controls +(-90:2) and +(-60:2)..(0,0); 
\draw[->] (0,0)--(3,0);
\draw[dashed] (3,0)--(4.5,0);
\pic [draw,pic text=\ang{60},angle radius=5mm,angle eccentricity=1.6]{angle=d--o--a};
\pic [draw,pic text=\ang{60},angle radius=6mm,angle eccentricity=1.6]{angle=b--o--d};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Teodorism Explanations added via comments written in the source code.

Comment: The '2' in $+(60:2)$, does it mean it's 2 cm away from the starting point (0,0)?

Comment: @Teodorism Yes, that's right. More precisely, at `2 cm` at a `60°` angle from point `(0.0)`.